# Way to go for dynamic components or routes in angular 6

Tags: angular

We have an Angular 6 enterprise application which has CRUD implemented for the products. We have following routes:

```
{ path: 'modules/products', component: ProductsComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.Products' }  },
{ path: 'modules/products/view-product', component: ViewProductComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.Products' } },
{ path: 'modules/products/create-or-edit-product', component: CreateOrEditProductComponent, data: { permission: 'Pages.Products.Edit' } },
```

Now from within the product page, we would like to create a 'Unit' selectbox component with the select option 'add new unit'. When selecting this option, we want to route the user to the create-unit path without losing his changes he didn't save yet in the product view.

The breadcrumbs for this would look like this:

Home > Prodcucts > Edit Prod01 > New Unit

We are looking for the best practice to achieve this.
We have following practices in mind:

### 1. Using dynamic child routes

Dynamically add the child paths from the onInit() function of the unit select box component. When selecting the 'add new unit' option, we save the current product data (component state?) in the onDestroy() function using a dataservice. After the new unit is created, we redirect back to the product page and load the unsaved product data.

### 2. Using hide/show multiple components

When selecting the 'add unit' option on the product page, we dynamically add the 'add unit' component to the page and show it while hiding the product component. After the new unit is created, we hide/remove the 'add unit' component and show the product component.

Can anyone point us in the right direction? All help/comments appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the second option is better and more *natural*. First option involves more overhead and can be notorious if you would use this in more components. There is also a higher chance to forgot about something, making this option more error prone.

But apart from options you provided, why not to leverage functionallity provided by Angular's Router which probably would fit your use case? Take a look at [auxiliary routes](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-router/#auxiliaryrouteswhataretheyandwhenaretheyuseful). Using this solution you don't have to explicitly care about dynamic component management and can pass it on to Angular's Router which will handle it in clean and safe manner.